# How can i hide toolbar menu item or whole toolbar depending on perspective in eclipse rcp?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to hide the toolbar item or whole toolbar when I m in specific perspective .
Till now I have tried to define a perspective extension and inside it i defined all the menubar and toolbar item needed to be hidden and linked them with the respective id.But  contrary to my expectation when i opened the application all the menu item are gone as expected but toolbar item are still visible.Is there anything which I am doing wrong here.

```
2nd approach :

    WorkbenchWindow window = (WorkbenchWindow) PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
                .getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
            window.setCoolBarVisible(b.getSelection());
            // window.toggleToolbarVisibility();
```

But here as window is an internal class so I  donot want to use this approach.
Any light on my first approach is appreciated ..

Comment: I think that what you are looking for is a propertytester. Here is an example: http://openchrom.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/showhide-menu-and-toolbar-entries-depending-on-the-selected-perspective/